# generate polynomial in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function which can print a polynomial of order n of x,y

i.e. `poly(x,y,1)` will output `c[0] + c[1]*x + c[2]*y`

i.e. `poly(x,y,2)` will output `c[0] + c[1]*x + c[2]*y + c[3]*x**2 + c[4]*y**2 + c[5]*x*y`

Could you give me some ideas? Maybe itertools?

Comment: The way your question is written, it reads like "please do my homework". You should really consider posting what you've tried so far

Comment: A polynomial of two variables needs a 2-dimensional matrix of coefficients (n x n).

Comment: Ideas: Lookup pascal's triangle, and how it relates to polynomial expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to start from something like

```
def poly(x,y,n):
    counter = 0
    for nc in range(n+1):
        for i in range(nc+1):
            print "c[", counter, "]",
            print " * ", x, "**", i,
            print " * ", y, "**", nc-i,
            print " + ",
            counter += 1
```

For example

```
poly("x", "y", 2)
```

will produce

```
c[ 0 ]  *  x ** 0  *  y ** 0  +  c[ 1 ]  *  x ** 0  *  y ** 1  +  c[ 2 ]  *  x ** 1  *  y ** 0  +  c[ 3 ]  *  x ** 0  *  y ** 2  +  c[ 4 ]  *  x ** 1  *  y ** 1  +  c[ 5 ]  *  x ** 2  *  y ** 0  +
```

Build in `if`s, if you want to suppress undesired output.

Answer (score 2):

Since you wanted a functional solution with itertools, here's a one-liner:

```
import itertools as itt
from collections import Counter
n = 3
xy = ("x", "y") # list of variables may be extended indefinitely
poly = '+'.join(itt.starmap(lambda u, t: u+"*"+t if t else u, zip(map(lambda v: "C["+str(v)+"]", itt.count()),map(lambda z: "*".join(z), map(lambda x: tuple(map(lambda y: "**".join(map(str, filter(lambda w: w!=1, y))), x)), map(dict.items, (map(Counter, itt.chain.from_iterable(itt.combinations_with_replacement(xy, i) for i in range(n+1))))))))))
```

That would give you

```
C[0]+C[1]*x+C[2]*y+C[3]*x**2+C[4]*y*x+C[5]*y**2+C[6]*x**3+C[7]*y*x**2+C[8]*y**2*x+C[9]*y**3
```

Note, the order of coefficients is slightly different. This will work not only for any n, but also for any number of variables (x, y, z, etc...)

Just for laughs

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more generalized:

```
from itertools import product

def make_clause(c, vars, pows):
    c = ['c[{}]'.format(c)]
    vp = (['', '{}', '({}**{})'][min(p,2)].format(v,p) for v,p in zip(vars,pows))
    return '*'.join(c + [s for s in vp if s])

def poly(vars, max_power):
    res = (make_clause(c, vars, pows) for c,pows in enumerate(product(*(range(max_power+1) for v in vars))))
    return ' + '.join(res)
```

then `poly(['x', 'y'], 2)` returns

```
"c[0] + c[1]*y + c[2]*(y**2) + c[3]*x + c[4]*x*y + c[5]*x*(y**2) + c[6]*(x**2) + c[7]*(x**2)*y + c[8]*(x**2)*(y**2)"
```